# Can't get project to build using fvm flutter

Tags: flutter, fvm

I'm trying to use fvm for my flutter version.

I'm running into many errors. Currently, I have this one:

> ../../fvm/versions/3.13.4/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart:329:80:
> Error: Member not found: 'hidden'.

I have noticed that is a new value added to `AppLifecycleState` enum called `hidden`. It is in my code when I navigate to it by cmd + clicking the error.....

It seems like it is fixed when I change:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.0 <3.2.0"
```

to

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.2 <4.0.0'
```

But then I get:

> Error (Xcode): [+1157 ms]
> .dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart:1:1: Error: The
> specified language version is too high. The highest supported language
> version is 3.0.

I did flutter clean so it will regenerate `.dart_tool` folder but it didn't fix it.

I think it is using my global dart, not my fvm dart because `fvm flutter doctor` shows:

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [!]
> Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.4, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64,
> locale en-GB)
> ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to /Users/ben/development/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not
> inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at
> /Users/ben/fvm/versions/3.13.4. Consider adding
> /Users/ben/fvm/versions/3.13.4/bin to the front of your
> path.
> ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /Users/ben/development/flutter/bin/dart, which is not
> inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at
> /Users/ben/fvm/versions/3.13.4. Consider adding
> /Users/ben/fvm/versions/3.13.4/bin to the front of your
> path. [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.3) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0) [✓]
> Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3) [✓]
> IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.2.2) [✓] VS Code
> (version 1.83.0) [✓] Connected device (6 available) [✓] Network
> resources
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Yes, it uses a global version of pub-cache which is a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use fvm and I often switch between projects for work and personal. This is the first time I've encountered this same exact error.

```
/fvm/versions/3.13.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart:329:80: Error: Member not found: 'hidden'.
```

I solved it by running

```
fvm flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

I'm not sure why this solved it but I assume it's due to something with the global pub-cache. Hope this helps!